# Can't redirect after login React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I'm relatively new to React and Redux, and I'm trying to manage a login system and authenticated routes. I currently have a login form that calls an action called `login` on submit, which changes the redux state to have `isAuthenticated` set to `true` and `user` set to whatever the user is.

I want to redirect the user back to the previous page from wherever they are logging in from, but when I log in, it gets redirected back to the home page before I get the chance to change the state of the login form to redirect back to referral, the component gets unmounted.

The code for the login form and login redux action is shown below. Thanks in advance for your help.

```js
class LoginForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        email: '',
        password: '',
        errors: {},
        redirectToReferrer: false
    };

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    this.login = login.bind(this);
  }

  onChange(e){
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const post = {
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password
    }

    this.props.login(post).then(
      (res) => this.setState(() =>{redirectToReferrer: true}),
      (err) => console.log(err)
    )
  }



  render(){
    const { redirectToReferrer } = this.state.redirectToReferrer;
    const { from } = {from: {pathname: '/client/games'}};

    if(redirectToReferrer === true){
      return(
        <Redirect to={from}  />
      )
    }

    return(
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <input type="text" id="email" onChange={this.onChange} name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
          <input type="password" id="password" onChange={this.onChange} name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
          <br />
          <button type="submit" className="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
        <br />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

LoginForm.contextTypes = {
  router: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}


LoginForm.propTypes = {
  from: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}


export default connect(null, { login })(LoginForm);
```

```js
export function setCurrentUser(token) { //action function to set user from given jwtToken
  return {
    type: SET_CURRENT_USER,
    user: token.user
  }
}

export function login(data) {
  return dispatch => {
    return axios.post('/users/login', data) //post login info to backend
    .then(res => {
      const token = res.data.token; //get the token from the response
      localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', token); //set the jwtToken
      dispatch(setCurrentUser(JWT.decode(token, 'authtoken'))); //dispatch currentUser action with the given decoded token
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure that we're using the same react-router. But I usually use push in my setup.

```
import { push } from "react-router-redux";

export const changeUrl = location => dispatch => dispatch(push(location));
```

Comment: So I tried implementing it by dispatching an action to push the location, however, if I look at the dev tools, I can see that the redux router state changes and goes to '/' right after the 'auth' reducer state changes to "authenticated: true, user: 'name_of_user'" and then after the dispatch(push(location)) it will go to the location I need. I don't think there should be any redirection to '/' at any point and I can't find anywhere in my code where I expicitly redirect to there, especially not after changing 'auth' reducer state. Also, when it gets to "location" the components don't load.

Comment: Hmm sounds strange. Do you dispatch in a new then-link?